# How can I specify a dynamic value type param in a Web API action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Some Context**

I'm trying to create a Web API controller that is able to work with any repository implementation.
The goal is to be able to change database implementations without having to touch the controller.

Repositories can work with different database types, hence have different PK column type.
SQL Server for example usually uses an int, while MongoDB usually uses strings.
In runtime my controller will get injected with the correct database implementation by using a repository interface.

**The Problem**

Dependency injection works well, and each repo implementation works by itself.
Problem arises at the action level in the controller.

Each repo has its own definition of the Id field. So the repo is generic.
But I can't mark the action param as generic. Where would it get the type from?
Another option is to set it as `dynamic`, but this means I have to write code to deduce the type of param I received at runtime and manually parsing or casting it before passing it to the repo.

**Some Code**

In a sense, I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```cs
// ----------------- Interfaces -----------------
interface IRepository
{
    Task<object> FindAsync(object id);
}

interface IRepository<TId> : IRepository where TId : struct
{
   Task<SomeData> FindAsync(TId id);
}

// ----------------- Base implementation -----------------
class SqlServerRepository : IRepository<int>
{
    public async Task<SomeData> FindAsync(int id) { ... }

    // Explicit implementation to allow access only through interface reference
    async Task<object> IRepository.FindAsync(object id) => await FindAsync((int)id);
}

class MongoDbRepository : IRepository<string>
{
    // Same example as SqlServerRepository but for string ids
}


// ----------------- The famous controller -----------------
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository db;

    public SomeController(IRepository db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IAsyncResult> Get(dynamic id) // <<<< Problem starts here
    {
        return await db.FindAsync(id);
    }
}
```

**My Question**

How can I go about specifying a generic param (or `dynamic`/anything else?) in the action, in a way that would simply allow me to pass it to the repo without casting, parsing or any manual labor?

Comment: Some reason you can't pass `id` as an `object`? That seems to be the intention behind the `IRepository` interface. What am I missing?

Comment: The `id` param is primitive. Marking the param as `object` leads to the action interpreting it as an object (debugger shows: `id = {object}`), meaning the value is not interpreted correctly. Same happens with `dynamic` BTW.

Comment: *meaning the value is not interpreted correctly* No it doesn't mean that. Have you tried it? Storing a value type in an `object` is called [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) and I assure you the original value is intact.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. I even tried casting it to the original type, but then I get an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using generics!
Ended up defining the controller as generic. This makes .NET Core ignore it so it doesn't get instantiated.

Moved the implementing repository class to a new assembly and added a controller that inherits the generic one to the new assembly.

When loading the main Web Api project, .NET Core iterates through all assembly references to find `ApplicationFeatures`, and automatically finds the new controller implementation!
Magic!

Now I can have my action parameters as generic.

```cs
/// ============ Main Project or Base Class Library =============
public class SomeController<TId> : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<TId> db;

    public SomeController(IRepository<TId> db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IAsyncResult> Get(TId id)
    {
        return await db.FindAsync(id);
    }
}

/// =========== New Assembly ============
public class SomeController : SomeController<int>
{
    public SomeController(IRepository<int> db) : base(db) { }
}
```

All that's left to do when changing the database implementation is to implement the generic repository, inherit the generic controller, and replace the reference of the implementing assembly in the main project!
Ta Daaa!! :)

I love .NET...